# Passing a Helper Class a Parameter Through a Layout XML File

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-layout-xml

I have a working link being added to the *top.links* block like this:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
    <action method="addLink">
        <label>About Us</label>
        <url helper="mymodule/getAboutUsUrl"/>
        <title>About Us</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>20</position>
    </action>
</block>
```

Eventually I wanted *getAboutUsUrl* to turn into *getExternalSiteUrl*. I want that one function to take parameters. For instance, *getExternalSiteUrl('about-us')* which would then return something like /the/url/about-us. However, I can't seem to find a way to send a helper class parameters in a Layout XML file. I searched for other modules doing this already, and couldn't find one in the Customer module where I searched.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
    <action method="addLink">
        <label>About Us</label>
        <url helper="mymodule/getAboutUsUrl">
            <arg>Now with more args!</arg>
            <!-- will result in the string being passed as first arg -->
        </url>
        <title>About Us</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>20</position>
    </action>
</block>
```

Note that helpers do not extend `Varien_Object`, therefore your method will need to explicitly define the `getAboutUsUrl()` method.